# Mongodb search special character (\) in a collection

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

How to search strings starting with '\' in  mongodb. Please help

```
db.txt.insert({"name": "\paul"})
db.txt.insert({"name": "Oracle"})
db.txt.insert({"name": "\Testing program"})
```

Output required:

```
\paul
\testing program
```

Comment: basically you want name that start with \ ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the [**`$regex`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/)   operator.

```js
db.txt.find({ "name": { "$regex": /^\\/ }})
```